# How to iterate over a 2D matrix in Python?

Tags: python, iteration

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how to set up iteration code, I build a matrix as a list of lists

```
for _ in range(rowsLen):
    self.matrixRC.append([2 for _ in range(collsLen)])
```

With the iteration code that I have at this moment it iterates in the wrong way.

```
def __iter__(self): 
    for i in self.matrixRC:
        for j in i:
            yield j


def __next__(self): 
    for i in self.matrixRC:
        for j in i:
            return j
```

By iterating in the wrong way I mean that it first shows me the values of `matrixRC[0][0]` then `matrixRC[0][1]` etc., but I want it to show `matrixRC[0][0]` then `matrixRC[1][0]`

Or if it already shows `matrixRC[0][0]` then `matrixRC[1][0]` then I would like it to show `matrixRC[0][0]` then `matrixRC[0][1]`. I'm really having trouble visualizing how this iteration code works (one of the few parts of code that I have copied).

Comment: Can you provide sample input and output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def __iter__(self): 
       for i in zip(*self.matrixRC):
            for j in i:
                yield j

    def __next__(self): 
        for i in zip(*self.matrixRC):
            for j in i:
                return j
```

Comment: What if dimensions are N x M where N != M?

Comment: What if you don't have any rows/columns? I think we should wait for more input from the OP :)

Comment: Thank you! I still don't get iteration but I guess i'll figure it out another time.

Comment: thanks @JayShankarGupta IDK zip yet, but it looks like it works xD

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
def __iter__(self): 
       yield from chain.from_iterable(zip(*(self.matrixRC or [])))

def __next__(self):
    return next(iter(self))
```

Comment: I don't think everything has to be one line :)

Comment: I bow down before the author of this answer.